# HTML Tag Attribute to Redirect the Page if the href Link is not Working

Tags: html

```
<a class="blue_link" data-href-backup="https://web.archive.org/web/20220313095141/https://dli.mt.gov/" href="http://dli.mt.gov/" target="_blank">http://dli.mt.gov/</a><br/>
```

Is the data-href-backup attribute above is the right one to be used, to redirect the page if the href link is not working?

Thanks

Comment: there is no such attribute in html, browser is not supposed to check whether links are working or not

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up some things here. There is no check in native `HTML` if a `href` is working. It is a markup language, not a programming language.

`data` attributes in general are used to add additional data to an element.
When a attribute name starts with `data-` it is a data attribute.

---

To realize such a link checking you could make requests with javascript that validate the `http response code`. If the response code is not `200` or some of the redirections like `301` you could replace the value of `href` of your given element.

---

Learn more about data attributes:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes